# How to mock PanacheQuery<Entity> using Quarkus with Hibernate-OMR PanacheRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, mocking, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am using Quarkus with Hibernate-ORM PanacheRepository and I need to mock the PanacheQuery.
I have the following classes:

- Label(JPA Entity)
- LabelRepository (implements PanacheRepository< Label > {})

In my test class I need to mock the **labelRepository.find("name", name)**. This method return a  PanacheQuery but I don't know how I can create a new PanacheQuery mock.

```
@QuarkusTest
class LabelResourceTest {

  @Inject LabelResource labelResource;
  @InjectMock LabelRepository labelRepository;

  private Label label;
  private List<Label> labels;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    label = new Label();
    label.setId(1L);
    label.setName("LABEL#01");
    label.setInheritable(true);

    labels = new ArrayList<>();
    labels.add(label);
  }

 @Test
 void getNameTest() {
  when(labelRepository.find("name", "LABEL#01")).thenReturn(......);

 .....

 }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good point !

Today, there is no easy way to mock a PanacheQuery. Depending on the Panache flavor, a PanacheQuery is backed with a JPA Query (for Hibernate) or a BSON Query (for MongoDB) and have the capability to act on this query object (for example, paginate).

As of today, you may need to create a Mock on the PanacheQuery interface and return this mock on your `when(labelRepository.find("name", "LABEL#01")).thenReturn(......);`.

Assuming you're using only the `PanacheQuery.page()` and the `PanacheQuery.list()` methods something like this (not tested should work):

```
PanacheQuery query = Mockito.mock(PanacheQuery.class);
Mockito.when(query.page(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(query);
Mockito.when(query.list()).thenReturn(labels);
```

I'll open an issue on Quarkus, maybe we can do better (provide a MockQuery) or maybe we should at least document this.

Another solution would be to encapsulate the various calls you make to the PanacheQuery object in a dedicated method inside your entity and mock this one like in this example: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#adding-entity-methods

Comment: The Quarkus issue is here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13251, don't hesitate to provides feedback

Comment: Thank you so much. I have solved the issue Mocking the PanacheQuery as you suggested. In the topic I share the final piece of code

Answer (score 4):

The final working piece of code (thanks to @loicmathieu):

```
PanacheQuery query = Mockito.mock(PanacheQuery.class);
 
Mockito.when(query.page(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(query);
 
Mockito.when(query.firstResultOptional()).thenReturn(Optional.of(label));
 
when(labelRepository.find("name", "LABEL#01")).thenReturn(query);
```

I my case I have used the firstResultOptional() method but you can replace it if you need to use the list() because you are getting the entire list and not only a single item.